# GNU parallel returning retired options error

Tags: gnu-parallel

I'm trying to understand how to use GNU parallel, specifically the followin

```
echo "dir/*" | parallel "./run_script"
```

but it returns the following errors

```
parallel: Error: -g has been retired. Use --group.
parallel: Error: -B has been retired. Use --bf.
parallel: Error: -T has been retired. Use --tty.
parallel: Error: -U has been retired. Use --er.
parallel: Error: -W has been retired. Use --wd.
parallel: Error: -Y has been retired. Use --shebang.
parallel: Error: -H has been retired. Use --halt.
parallel: Error: --tollef has been retired. Use -u -q --arg-sep -- and --load for -l.
```

Does it require input parameters for these options? Seems like these all have default values.

Comment: What were you actually hoping to do?

Comment: Try running `echo “dir/*”` on its own to see if that does what you want.